# How to apply transition to an element which is set to display:none?

Tags: css, animation

I have a div, in css:

```
    #move_me{
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0F0;

    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 1s linear;* 
    }
```

I've a button also, with a clicklistener assigned in JC:

```
$("#display_command").click(function(e) {
    console.log("asd");

    $("#move_me").css("display", "block");
    $("#move_me").css("opacity", 1);
});
```

It does not animate the div, simply displays it. If I remove display:none from css it does the animation smoothly.
So how can I make the animation work with the display:none property?

I have to set it to display:none because I dont want it to take up any space on the flow until the button is being clicked.

Comment: share more codes or jsFiddle

Comment: If you are using jQuery you can use [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). `$("#move_me").fadeIn();`

Comment: Is your div called `animate_me` or `move_me`?

Comment: the div called move_me, sorry (edited)

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/72LNE/)

in order to apply transition you have to use opacity like this:

```
#animate_me{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:#0F0;
   opacity:0;    
   transition:opacity 1s linear;
}

#animate_me.opacityTransition{ 
   opacity:1; 
}
```

Js:

```
$("#display_command").click(function(e) {
   $("#animate_me").toggleClass("opacityTransition");
});
```

html:

```
<div id=animate_me>animate_me</div>
<button id=display_command>#display_command</button>
```

and if you want to animate the height and the opacity:

```
#animate_me{
   width:100px;
   height:0;
   background-color:#0F0;
   opacity:0;
   overflow:hidden;    
   transition:height 300ms linear, opacity 1s linear;
}

#animate_me.opacityTransition{ 
  opacity:1; 
  height:100px;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/72LNE/2/)

Comment: The CSS ID is `animate_me`, but JS is `move_me`.

Comment: kougiland, your solution does the animation, the problem is, I dont want the div to take up any space on the document flow before clicking the button. if there are elements in the div, and the div is hidden with opacity:0 I might click on a button, or focus on a textview, etc. before its actually visible.